# Alternative to using an atom

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a small Clojurescript program that has an atom. A String gets put into this atom that is configuration for a function (`low-level-fn`) that is used by practically every other function in the program. There is one entry point for the program where all the configuration is received. The running structure of this program is an upside down tree where many of the leaves are actually `low-level-fn`.

My intention was always to get rid of this atom as part of finishing off the program - by making it a higher order function with the configuration String passed into the outer function. Either that or doing the same thing by adding a leftmost parameter that is the String config and creating a partial function. In either case this 'yet to be completed' function being constructed in the entry point function.

My problem is that the program will arguably become worse than it was with the atom, since the 'yet to be completed' function will have to be passed down as a parameter through almost all of the functions in the program.

Are there any other ideas I should be considering? I most likely will get rid of the atom to make the whole program one pure function. *edit* - actually with or without the atom, the program is still a pure function. *edit* - or is it?

Comment: *"the program will arguably become worse [...] since the 'yet to be completed' function will have to be passed down as a parameter through almost all of the functions in the program"* Why is passing a function worse than passing an atom?

Comment: When reading the program there will be this extra parameter to consider for almost every function, that is about a low-level concern, unrelated to the function in question. The program will be much cleaner without it.

Comment: Is the configuration expected to change on execution? If not, you can just use a Var at the very beginning like `(def configuration your-reading-config-function)`.

Comment: Not during execution but this is a library and the user supplies the config String.

Comment: My point is: why not load the whole configuration in a map for example then just access this map?

Comment: Yes that is the way it is done - map for everything passed in at the top. Perhaps 'user configuration' is actually considered a pretty good reason to have an atom. In fact in this program the other parts of the configuration are passed down properly from the top, so it is currently 'hedging its bets' on the best way to go.

Comment: I agree with m0skit0. Pure functional design is very clean, but as soon as you hit limitations, you should use clojure's possibilites and find a safe way of storing your variables in some kind of state. If you have only one init function, make that init function use ```defonce``` for your atom or whatever value you have, so repeated calls of ```init``` won't modify the first value and you can proceed happily.

Comment: If you use it this way, then it is not an "atom" since it will not be rewritten at any time. It is an immutable map (created once and then only read).

Comment: This really is a pure function so if the user called with different arguments she should get a different response.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to generate one function depending on user input and then call this function repeatedly. A new input should create a different function and re-run the program. In this case, relying on an atom is false security - imagine you call the function from two concurrent threads before one of the threads has finished - in this case, the function will be changed for both threads when the atom is modified. In that case, I'm not sure if there is an alternative to passing any information (or better, the function) onwards.

Comment: You could be making a pretty good point there - that atoms can be dangerous in libraries. That one invocation could receive another invocation's state. I never thought of that.

Comment: Chris, have you consider a `binding` of the string at the HOF? (this assumes all LLF are invoked from this point).

Comment: No. Never used binding. Would it have the same advantages/benefits as using an atom? A shortcut method like this could be a valid answer as long as 'only use it when...', 'because otherwise...terrible consequences' are stated.

Comment: Chris - If you can update your question with a snippet of usage I would be able to answer the question if it is suitable. An example of where I used it is a recursive multi-method traversal where the context is set (bound) to a `(def ^:dynamic *current-context*)`.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/chrismurrph/default-db-format/blob/master/src/default_db_format/core.cljs) is the file in question. The recent commits are 'Before remove the atom' and 'Now no atom, but polluted with functions'.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand your problem correctly, the easiest way to do is using closures.

What about the following:

```
(defn myrunner [param]
  ;; generate closures depending on the parameter
  (letfn [(my-fn [x]
            (* param x))]
    ;; now process everything inside the letfn
    (my-fn 2)))

(myrunner 2) ;; => 4
(myrunner 6) ;; => 12
;; parallel execution works, too
(pmap myrunner (range 100)) ;; 0, 2, 4,...
```

Edit: Removed side-effects from example.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that in the REPL... will edit, just a moment.

Comment: Thanks sorry I deleted my comment. Was suggesting less maths and no side effects, which has now been done.

Comment: Sorry - I've been really sloppy here.

Comment: So it seems in my question I should have said closure or higher order or partially applied function. They all really amount to the same thing - binding a variable into a function. Still the most important point is whether having an atom in a library/function is dangerous. That would 100% sway me away from considering atom for config.

Comment: It is not dangerous by definition. If you can ensure your code will never be run concurrently, it is propably alright. You need to think very carefully of your design. Atoms present mutable state, so you need to always have in mind that your atom might have been changed. In your particular case I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
(defn original-lowlv-fn [cfg param]
  ;; your lowlevel fun that needs config
  (prn cfg param))


(defn init-library [cfg-from-user]
  ;; init-library must be called before library use
  ;; your new lowlevel-fn
  (def lowlv-fn
    (let [cfg {:my-cfg cfg-from-user}]
      (partial original-lowlv-fn cfg))))
```

Example:

```
(lowlv-fn :foo)
```

Comment: @chris-murphy since I can only comment on my own solutions yet: a atom can be changed during the runtime of a program. it represents state and if one has read your program/library his has to check now, where the state changes. if you use a partial/closure this ambiguity will not occur

Comment: With your solution the user would have to call init-library and then give back what is returned to the entry level function. Just easier if the user calls the entry level function with cfg-from-user in the first place and lets the entry level function call init-library on her behalf.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy I'm not claiming that my solution is good. It's in fact a hack. I want to give a solution that gets away with only a few lines of code change. All I want to point out with my comment is that an atom represents state, and that's something you want to avoid in functional programs.